# trigger click jquery for all elements

Tags: php, jquery, click

I have the following information in my html

```
<div idd="8327" id="like" class="geen">Like</div>
<div idd="8329" id="like" class="geen">Like</div>
<div idd="8330" id="like" class="geen">Like</div>
<div idd="8331" id="like" class="geen">Like</div>
```

I want to send the ID to a specific php page to execute with .get.
it works. but it only works for the first div. The script is only executed when clicking the div with id 8327. When clicking another div, nothing happens :

What can be wrong ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#like").click(function(event){
    var code =  $(this).attr("idd");
    $.get("like.php", { code1: code, code2: "Kim" } );    
        alert("Thanks for clicking!");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The id must be unique. Change it for a class and it must work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use the id selector in Jquery you only select the first element so to get all elements use a class selector instead. So change:

```
$("#like").click(
```

To

```
$(".geen").click(
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch your selector to use the class. jQuery assumes that `#` (id) is unique and will use the built in browser function `document.getElementById()`.

```
$(".geen").click(function(event){

    var code =  $(this).attr("idd");

    $.get("like.php", { code1: code, code2: "Kim" } );    

    alert("Thanks for clicking!");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use your class as selector because id can not be duplicate( which is in your case)

So through this

```
$(".geen").click(function(event){

var code =  $(this).attr("idd");

$.get("like.php", { code1: code, code2: "Kim" } );    
alert("Thanks for clicking!");

});
```